# get SSL error when I install TPM emulator

Tags: ubuntu, tpm

I try to install TPM emulator on Ubuntu 16.04 and get ssl error at tpmd_dev

- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
  sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  so I cant install emulator.

i try to remove openssl and libssl-dev and install again
even i create a new virtual machine and do it again 
it still cant work.

i just start to learn tpm emulator, just this target:tpmd_dev

```
twist@ubuntu:~/Downloads/tpm/build/tpmd_dev$ sudo make install
[100%] Built target tpmd_dev
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It appears to be looking for a relative path to `certs/signing_key.pem` - does that exist?

Comment: thanks!finally I generate a signing_key.pem file and finish installation